# ...with Properties {name:"***"} not working

Tags: applescript, iwork

Sorry if this is a noob question, I am just trying to learn this lovely program known as applescript.

tell application "Numbers" ¬
     activate
end

tell application "Numbers" to ¬
     make new document with properties {name:"document 3"}
end

I can use this format of script to open most any other application (other than iWork) and it will open up, make a new document, and name it, but for whatever reason it will not work with iWork.

I have even tried to set a variable to use in the {name:variable} or {name:"variable"} with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

PS...Snide comments will be tolerated if they bring me the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do have Numbers. Try this:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    set myDoc to make new document with properties {name:"document 3"}
    name of myDoc
end tell
```

The results window should show `"document 3"`. Why do you say it is not working? Possibly because the **window** that contains the document is labeled "Untitled"? That's because a window does not show the document name until the document is saved. If you choose "Save" from the menu, you will see your document name right there in the save dialog, and the window title will update ***after*** the save.

Answer (score 0):

i do not have "numbers" on my computer, would you try this:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    make new document at front with properties {name:"hello darkness"}
end tell
```

replace "textedit" with "numbers"

have fun :)

ok, try this one:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    make new document at front
    tell document 1
        set name to "hello darkness"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I just did exactly what you suggested... It didn't work. Sill untitled. Since I am working on another party of my script, I figured I would put some generic info into the new spreadsheet anyways for testing some other stuff I am doing.... As soon as I edited the blank spreadsheet it changed its name to hello darkness! I guess I just need to edit it for it to realize I actually want the name to change.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I also do not have Numbers to test this, but this should work in theory.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    set mydoc to make new document
    set name of mydoc to "My New Document"
end tell
```

In my opinion this approach is "safer" than the previous answer because you are capturing a reference to the document that you've just created rather than getting a generic reference to "document 1" after you create your document. Most of the time, you should have an issue with the "document 1" approach, but the time you do, it will be very frustrating and cause a lot of confusion.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep the whole solution within applescript, which allows creation without intervention:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    set nDoc to make new document
    save nDoc in file ((path to desktop as text) & "crap.numbers")
end tell
```

While these Numbers commands (make, save) have multiple parameters, they don't seem to work as defined in the dictionary.